# Access to Dash's documentation from PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, plotly-dash

I'm playing with Plotly's Dash library using PyCharm as my IDE. Since I'm not familiar with the API and html in general, I'm recurring to the documentation pretty often calling the `help` command in the integrated python console, because the documentation shortcut from PyCharm (`Ctrl + Q` in my case) doesn't work for the `dash_core_components` and `dash_html_components`.

I'm wondering if there's a less cumbersome way to access the documentation, I tried to assign a shortcut key to the help command with no success

Comment: I would love to see a solution to this. I would also like to see code completion in pycharm. There is probably some codegen/metaprogramming that needs to be done to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + Q` probably doesn't show anything because the `__init.py__` of `dash_core_components` has no documentation.

However, you can hold `Ctrl` and `left click` on the `dash_core_components` import statement to explore the package. Here are a few lines of the code you will find:

```
_components = _dash.development.component_loader.load_components(
    _os.path.join(_current_path, 'metadata.json'),
    'dash_core_components'
)
```

If you now do `Ctrl + Q` on `load_component` you will see the docstring of this function.